# Does request_uri() have to be filtered or escaped?

Tags: 7, navigation

Mind my ignorance, but I'm trying to understand whether or not calling request_uri(), and then echoing output from it into a link is safe.

What I'm doing is getting arguments from the URL, for example:

```
$exploded_url = explode('/', request_uri());
echo $exploded_url[3];
```

My questions: is this function's output being escaped/filtered already? Would it be overkill for me to do it again? What would be the way to ensure that it is safe? Is there another/better function I should or could use?

Thanks, any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you need to sanitise the variable yourself.

All `request_uri()` does is pass the raw input from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` (or from a different source if the server is not Apache). Apache/PHP does nothing by default to sanitise the `$_SERVER` variables on your behalf so they should be considered unsafe.

There's an excellent answer to [Which $_SERVER variables are safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474783/which-server-variables-are-safe) on StackOverflow that goes into a lot more detail, and actually notes that `REQUEST_URI` "may contain tainted data".

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for the best ways to escape/ filter this to make it safe?

Comment: I think a combination of [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) will do the trick for the `REQUEST_URI` variable.

Comment: I also found some more info here: http://drupal.org/node/28984

"Note that all Drupal functions which return URLs (url(), request_uri(), etc.) output plain URLs which have not been HTML escaped in any way (in other words, they are plain-text). Remember to use check_url() to escape them when outputting HTML (or XML). Don't use check_url() in situations where a real URL is expected, e.g. in the HTTP Location: ... header."